# Angular JS unauthorized redirect takes 3-5 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I've already make my authorization system with angular. all the checking is working great. But there is a problem:

If user is unauthorized i redirect them to login page. But the problem is before it get redirect to login page, the request keep getting through for specific second and redirect them. 
ex: user(unauthorized) open /dashboard. it needs 3-5 seconds to redirect them to login page. So, before 3-5 seconds it show the dashboard page for a moment.

Here is my route:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth/login');

    $stateProvider
        .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: '/app/views/dashboard.html'
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/auth/login',
            templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html'
        })
}])
```

Here is my code using factory interceptor:

```
.factory('httpRequestInterceptor', function ($q, $window, $base64, $location)   
{
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'someKey';

            return config;
        },
        response: function(response){

            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            if(response.status == 401){
                $location.path('/auth/login');
            }
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})

.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpRequestInterceptor');
}]);
```

What should i add to make it redirect it directly without opening dashboard?

Comment: Do you use link to redirect to dashboard?

Comment: sorry i don't get what you mean. can you be more specific?. I've added my routes

Comment: I am wondering how you change state to the Dashboard? Do you handle it as a link, or in your controller?